# I want to create inside Corner Radius on center of view corners in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a React-Native UIView that has a reversed-inverted corner radius on all four corners With a transparent background like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

css tricks like this should work:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const App = () => {

    const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width; // could use hooks for this too.

    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 100, backgroundColor: 'white', width: '100%', height: 50, flexDirection: 'row'}} >
              <View style={{left: -25, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 90}} />
              <View style={{left: -75 + DEVICE_WIDTH, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 90}} />
          </View>
      </View>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but  I have a transparent background, and you have added two circle view of the main view. so transparent not showing.

Comment: i am not quite sure i understand, but won't it be fine if you make the whole background transparent and the circles white?

Comment: I have set the background image and the circle need to a transparent. so the curve area should be visible.